# Count Full Set of Possible Ordered Pairs for k-Many Elements (nCr Equation)

Tags: combinatorics

I am confused with counting ordered pairs. I think that I understand the standard kCr equation. But, I don't understand how to apply it when the k varies. For example, suppose I want to count ordered pairs for k=4 and these are binary pairs (x, y). I want to include the empty set as well as singletons in my count - not just the doubletons. How do I do this?

Comment: To find the number of subsets consisting of $0$, $1$, or $2$ elements, do the counts separately for $0$, $1$, and $2$ and add.

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to count? If you want to count ordered pairs from a set of $3$ elements, there are $3^2$. If you want to find the number of ways of choosing $0$ or $1$ or $2$ (distinct) elements, the number of ways is $7$. Maybe you could start from a set $A$ of say $5$ people, or numbers, and specify *exactly* what you want to count.  No math symbols, just an informal but precise description.

Comment: The set of all possible ordered pairs for elements {x, y, z} is 10 = {∅, x, y, z, xy, xz, yx, yz, zx, zy}. So, what I have been doing is as described and then adding one for the empty set. I was told this was wrong though. So, let's use you example - a Set A with 5 people. And say, I am throwing a party in which these five people have been invited. If they choose to attend, they are free to arrive by themselves or with one other guest (I have a car with two seats to fetch them). But, it remains possible that none will attend. How then do I account for all of the possible ordered pairs, incl ∅?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We answer the more detailed explicit question of the comment. We have $5$ people, and want to count the collection consisting of the empty set, all one-element sets, and all **ordered** pairs of **distinct** people.

Empty set: $1$

One-element sets: $\binom{5}{1}$, or more simply $5$.

Ordered pairs of distinct elements: $(5)(4)$. That is because the first element of the ordered pair can be chosen in $5$ ways, and for each of these ways the second element can be chosen in $4$ ways.

Add. We get $26$.

Let us do this more generally with $n$ people. The three numbers are $1$, $n$, and $n(n-1)$. Add. We get $1+n+n^2-n$, which simplifies to $n^2+1$.

**Remark:** It may be that you are only interested in counting the number of possible contents of the car. Then for pairs, we would want to count *unordered* pairs. If Beti and Cassandra show up, that is the same as Cassandra and Beti. In that case we would have
$$\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}.$$
In the case $n=5$, we get $16$.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - thanks! Suppose one last thing. If I wanted all ordered pairs and I dropped the distinct criteria. So, the first and the second components of the ordered pair could be the same. Would I just calculate: Empty Set = 1; One Element Set = 5; Ordered Pairs = (5)(5) for a total of 31?

Comment: Yes, exactly, the answer is $1+5+5^2$.  And if you wanted to add ordered triples to the count, you would use $1+5+5^2+5^3$.